# Zend_Form getErrors

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have a form.
It's checked: `$isValid = $form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())`

The problem is errors are empty.
`$form->getErrors()` returns array `{"field1": [], "field2": [], "field3": [], "field4": []}` when form is invalid.

So inner arrays are empty. What should I do to find why form is invalid?
Code is not developed by me, but there is nothing suspicious in it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `$form->getMessages()` to get the error messages.

```
 $form->isValid($this->_getAllParams());
 $form_messages = $form->getMessages();
```

Comment: getMessages returns one empty array.

Comment: The problem field is file field.

Comment: `$this->getRequest()->getPost()` is same as `$this->_getAllParams()` right?

Comment: No, `$this->getRequest()->getPost()` returns only `POST` params. `$this->_getAllParams()` returns all params, including url params and `GET` and dynamically added params.